# Use locations with google distance matrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, distance

I am a newbie ith google maps distance matrix. But I need it to calculate most effecient route between several locations.

However using a jsfiddle example I can even make it create a route with locations in my region:

1. [My Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XxuJ4/130/)
2. [Example js Fiddle tha I used as base](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_weaver/XxuJ4/)

Basically changed destinations to:

```
var origin = "Aeroporto da Madeira"
var destinations = [
    "Hotel Four Views Baía, Rua das Maravilhas, Funchal",
    "R. José Joaquim da Costa 112, 9325-031 Estreito De Câmara, Portugal",
    "Q.ta de São João, 2735-521, Portugal"];
```

These places exist and if I search at google maps appear.
This maybe a very stupid question but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have an error in the console (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined) at this line ( tmp = routes.elements[i].duration.value;) so it looks like value is not set

Comment: Hotel Four Views Baía is not a valid address, that probably can't be located accurately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that an address may be geocoded must not mean that a route may be calculated to another location.

In your case the origin is on madeira(an island), but the last destination isn't placed on madeira(a driving route may not be calculated....obviously there are no ferries available...., your function stops running because of the attempt to access a undefined variable `routes.elements[i].duration.value`)

check the `status` of the `element` before you access it's properties

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var origin = "Aeroporto da Madeira"
var destinations = [
  "Hotel Four Views Baía, Rua das Maravilhas, Funchal",
  "R. José Joaquim da Costa 112, 9325-031 Estreito De Câmara, Portugal",
  "Q.ta de São João, 2735-521, Portugal"
];
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin], //array of origins
    destinations: destinations, //array of destinations
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);
}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    //we only have one origin so there should only be one row
    var routes = response.rows[0];

    //need to find the shortest 
    var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    var tmp;
    var shortestRouteIdx = -1;
    var resultText = "Possible Routes: <br/>";
    for (var i = routes.elements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //do  we got a result for the element?
      if (routes.elements[i].status === google.maps.DistanceMatrixElementStatus.OK) {
        tmp = routes.elements[i].duration.value;
        resultText += "Route " + destinations[i] + ": " + tmp + "<br/>";
        if (tmp < lowest) {
          lowest = tmp;
          shortestRouteIdx = i;
        }
      }
    }
    //log the routes and duration.
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = resultText;
    if (shortestRouteIdx > -1) {
      //get the shortest route
      var shortestRoute = destinations[shortestRouteIdx];
      //now we need to map the route.
      calculateRoute(origin, shortestRoute)
    } else {
      alert('no route available');

    }

  }
}

//Calculate the route of the shortest distance we found.
function calculateRoute(start, end) {
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(32.670159, -16.978268);
  var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: centerPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calculateDistances();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#results {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="results"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```